# In laravel 7 storage points to old path

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-7

I created laravel 7 project in my **/home/namiq/projects/airblog** folder.

After I finished my works I copied project files to **/var/www/airblog** folder in my pc. When I try to open web site it says

```
The stream or file "/home/namiq/projects/airblog/storage/logs/laravel-2020-07-18.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied
```

**So what is the problem?**

**Why it points to old path?**

**How to change storage folder to point to new path?**

Comment: You haven"t changed your symbolic link. ssh to server and run ```php artisan storage:link```. That should overwrite it I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I usually deploy using git, that's why I always have to do a

```
composer install
```

once my files are on the server. Maybe that will help in your case, too?
Maybe also try a

```
composer dump
```

To generate new autoload files first.